# css textbox border on google chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, border

I would like to keep only bottom border of a textbox. Here is my css-

```
    input[type="text"],input[type="password"] {          
        border:0px;
        border-bottom:1px solid black;
    }

    input[type="text"]:focus, input[type="password"]:focus {    
         border-bottom:2px solid green;                          
    }
```

Here is how it looks at-

On chrome-

[image]

On firefox-

[image]

On chrome, textbox gets a outline when it got focus. Is there any way to remove it?

Comment: this outline is meant to show wich form element has focus for the user.  `outline:none;` would remove it. is it really that bad ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
input[type="text"]:focus, input[type="password"]:focus {    
       outline:none;
     border-bottom:2px solid green;                          
}
```

you are missing outline:none.